# Junit Tests with Spring Boot Actuator gives Exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

When I enable Actuators in my Spring Boot application, my Junit tests failed with a NullPointer Exception.
The actuators are working fine, and the tests were working fine before I added the actuator artifact in my pom.xml file.

Seems like the

```
@MockBean
MailSender mailSender;
```

is causing the problem

My pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

My Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
public class MailServiceTest extends CommonServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    MailService mailService;

    @MockBean
    MailSender mailSender;

    private static final String TO = "user@test.com";
    private static final String SUBJECT = "Subject";
    private static final String TEXT = "Text";
    private static final String TOKEN = "1234";

    @Value("${app.email.from}")
    private String fromEmail;

    @Value("${app.email.support}")
    private String supportEmail;

    private ArgumentCaptor<SimpleMailMessage> simpleMailMessageCaptor;

    @Override
    public void initObjects() {
        simpleMailMessageCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(SimpleMailMessage.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void initMocks() {

    }

    @Test
    public void sendMailTest() {

        mailService.sendMail(TO, SUBJECT, TEXT);

        verify(mailSender).send(simpleMailMessageCaptor.capture());

        assertEquals(TO, simpleMailMessageCaptor.getValue().getTo()[0]);
        assertEquals(SUBJECT, simpleMailMessageCaptor.getValue().getSubject());
        assertEquals(fromEmail, simpleMailMessageCaptor.getValue().getFrom());
        assertEquals(TEXT, simpleMailMessageCaptor.getValue().getText());
    }

}
```

The error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$MailHealthIndicatorConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator]: Factory method 'mailHealthIndicator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator]: Factory method 'mailHealthIndicator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.CompositeHealthIndicatorConfiguration.createHealthIndicator(CompositeHealthIndicatorConfiguration.java:42)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$MailHealthIndicatorConfiguration.mailHealthIndicator(HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.java:334)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$MailHealthIndicatorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$25b5897.CGLIB$mailHealthIndicator$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$MailHealthIndicatorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$25b5897$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$da72ce26.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$MailHealthIndicatorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$25b5897.mailHealthIndicator(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 47 more
```

Comment: similar issue when executing unit test that references a class from another dependency.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem with the JavaMailSender class and Actuator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only solution I found was to add a properties in the test itself:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
// Otherwise I have a NullPointer, don't know why
@TestPropertySource(
        properties = {"management.health.mail.enabled=false"})
public class MailServiceTest extends CommonServiceTest {
```

Comment: as  @pandemicGander pointed it's needed also mock beans dependent on mailSender, e.g. MailHealthIndicatorConfiguration

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Leamas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2643469/leamas)  suggestion I would like to add, that this case can occur if you have used `@MockBean` to mock the `MailSender`, in this case it seems that the `MockedMailSender` is not found by the MailHealthIndicator. This was the case for me and disabeling the MailHealthIndicator using Leamas suggestion worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a symptom of having some proxy class wrapping your `JavaMailSenderImpl`.

Check that you use interfaces in your dependencies e.g. `JavaMailSender` and you'll see that `HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.MailHealthIndicatorConfiguration` finds and populates `mailSenders`:

```
public MailHealthIndicatorConfiguration(
        ObjectProvider<Map<String, JavaMailSenderImpl>> mailSenders) {
    this.mailSenders = mailSenders.getIfAvailable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below properties in application-test.properties, it will disable default configurations

`eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false`
`eureka.client.fetch-registry=false`
`eureka.client.enabled=false`